# Where to find information on how to initiate certain input type events in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Would you please tell me where to find information on how a user could initiate these input types while typing in a textarea element? This [W3C Editor's Draft](https://rawgit.com/w3c/input-events/v1/index.html#interface-InputEvent-Attributes) lists the input types, many of which are common, but several are not common to me. For example, I didn't know that CTRL + Backspace deleted the entire previous word; and that is not given in the draft.

How can a user perform "deleteSoftLineBackward" in a textarea, for example, and that short list of different types of soft and hard deletions of lines of text?

Is it always by key strokes of some type, or are there other ways?

The reason I ask is I'm building an undo/redo chain for a textarea that will replace that in the browser because user-triggered button events alter the value of the textarea and break the browser's undo chain. Mosts of it works well for my limited needs, but some of these events I simply don't know how to perform as a user composing in a textarea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some really interesting information in [the GitHub related to the documentation you linked](https://github.com/w3c/input-events).

In the "Issues" section, you've one in particular which aims to "[Create an overview of which inputtypes are used on which platform](https://github.com/w3c/input-events/issues/30)".

Then you've the [support document in a Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IQx8UJR6e4Tqakayx1gY7m3Nn5K8CwZgNdfYViO-0T8/edit#gid=1982068042) which should answer your question and provide you with enough information.

NB: to test these, I recommend you a tool like an [inputEvent viewer](https://d-toybox.com/studio/lib/input_event_viewer.html)...

Comment: Thank you. The spreadsheet doesn't list any of those softline and hardline type of deletions. Perhaps there is not a key event or menu item in a browser to perform them at this time, which makes my work a little easier for now at least. Thanks for the link to the inputEvent viewer. I have been using it because it is in Mozilla MDN but I don't think one can make it return one of those uncommon deletion input types because there's no way for a user to intitiate one in a textarea.